# why pointer variable not showing 100 digits?

Tags: c, pointers

aim: i had a requirement for accuracy i need 100 digits to be displayed or atleast 50 digits

try 1: first i had used integer variable then it displayed only 10 digits

try 2: with the help of my friend i used pointers concept it successfully had input 50 to 100 digits but pointer variable display only 10 digits

the program i had written was

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() 
 {
    int *p;
    p=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    *p=1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
    printf("%d",*p); 
 }
```

on executing the above procedure i'm getting a garbage value

thanks in advance

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warnings (`-Wall` at _least_ for GCC). Your code has more problems than lines of code.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` instead of `<string.h>`, and you are reserving space for an array of 100 `int`'s, not for an `int` capable to represent 100 digits

Comment: Have you thought about this number. 2 digits about the size of a class/team, 4 digits in terms of a school. 5  digits a small village 6 digits a small city. 8 digits we are talking capitals. (BTW not up to 10 yet). Not we need bacteria in your gut to the 10s millions. Get the picture

Comment: Decimal places and pointers have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: The python language has big number support by default.  Just so you don't waste too much time reinventing the wheel...

Comment: 1. A pointer doesn't **display** anything, it only stores the address to some object. 2. `malloc` is defined in `stdlib.h`. 3. [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), it'll hide problems when malloc is undefined because of not including stdlib.h like in your case

Comment: That one doesn't even compile for me. I get an C2177 "constant too large". What ehm ... smart compiler do you use that eats this construct w/o complaining? BTW, the line `p=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));` alone should make you think about what you are trying to do. You want an `int` with 100x the size of an `int` ... [and you honestly expect this to work](http://therewillbeasia.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/indiatrain.jpg)?

Comment: You see to be confusing 100 *digits* and 100 *integers*

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (arbitrary precision big numbers) library, since native `int` or `long` have a precision limited by the C implementation - ie the hardware (often 32 or 64 bits; see also `<stdint.h>` header and  `int32_t` & `int64_t` types). I suggest using [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/); you need to be fluent in C to use such libraries. Read [documentation of GMLib](https://gmplib.org/manual/).

<sup>Don't try to code bignumber arithmetic yourself. You'll use inefficient algorithms. Efficient algorithms for bignums are difficult to understand and to invent. You can still get a PhD on that. So use some *existing* bignum library.</sup>

So you might code something like the following to multiply your bignum by 137 and print the result

```
mpz_t bign;
mpz_t bigr;
// initialize bign from a literal string
mpz_init_set_str (bign,
                 "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
                 "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
                 10);
// initialize bigr
mpz_init(bigr);
/// compute bigr = bign * 137 (137 is a long, not a bignum)
mpz_mul_si(bigr, bign, 137L);
/// print bigr on stdout in base 10
mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, bigr);
/// clear all the numbers
mpz_clear(bign);
mpz_clear(bigr);
```

On a Linux system with GMP installed, you could compile such a code (in `yoursource.c`) using:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -lgmp -o yourprog
```

On other systems you might need some `-I` and `-L` arguments to `gcc`. When you have debugged your program, ask the compiler to optimize it with `-O2`

Notice that some languages (Common Lisp, Scheme, Python) have built-in bignums.

BTW, your `main` function is *incorrectly* defined. It should be defined as `int main(int argc, char**argv)` ...

Comment: This is interesting. +1 :)

Comment: Another language with big integer support is Tcl.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first part, a single `signed integer` (assuming 32 bits) can take values between -2,147,483,648 and +2,147,483,647

This is where your ten digits comes from.

Depending on your compiler, you may have `unsigned long long` available (64 bits) but that still only offers you a maximum or `0..18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (20 digits)

To handle 100-digit numbers will require some jiggery-pokery!

Comment: Like implementing a BCD algorithm or using a library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) to allow for numbers of arbitrary precision. Of course, it has its own printf function since the standard one cannot handle such a type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store such a long digit in an `int` variable or a pointer which is pointing to type `int`.

If `int` is of 32 bit, the range is [−2147483647,+2147483647]. [C data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

To store the large value you can use a char pointer and initialized it with the string constant.

For example:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() 
{
    char *p = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    printf("%s\n",p); 
}
```

Comment: You mean 32 bits not bytes

Comment: @1336087 thanks for reply but can you suggest which type of data type is used for storing 100 digits and display those 100 digits

Answer (score 2):

```
int * p = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
```

Allocates memory for an array of 100 `int`.

```
*p= ....
```

In fact is the same as

```
p[0]=...
```

So this

```
*p=1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
```

assigns to an `int`.

An `int` may hold not more then a 32 bits (less on some platforms). The largest 32bit (positive) integer is `2147483647`.

Answer (score 2):

C is a language close to the hardware. So you need to understand the storage capabilities and limitations of its data types.

An int on a PC is only able to store 32 bit or 64 bit values, depending on your hardware and OS version.

Yes, you can implement routines for handling larger value, and using a linked list of digits is one way do it.

Comment: Don't re-implement Bignum arithmetic by yourself. The algorithms are difficult if you want them to be efficient. Use some existing Bignum library!

Comment: The question gives no background. It might be an assignment for some programming education or a requirement during application development. In the latter case the advice to stick to existing tested code would hold for any non trivial piece of software.